# How to replace a command with an environment by using a macro in TexStudio?

Tags: environments, texstudio

My document has many commands like

```
\solution{
...
}
```

Now, I want to replace all those commands with

```
\begin{solution}
...
\end{solution}
```

Is there any way to do this with a macro?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean you literally want to replace `\solution{Foo}` with `\begin{solution}Foo \end{solution}` in your code?

Comment: What about using regex? (this doesn't have much to do with TeX though.)

Comment: A slight confusion is that TeX calls `\solution` a macro.  Changing `\solution{` to `\begin{solution}` (along the lines of what Ingmar suggests) would be a simple search and replace.  Spotting the `}` to become `\end{solution}` would be much harder, and probably best done manually alongside the search and replace.

Comment: @Teepeemm: If that's what he wants, it doesn't have to be hard at all. “Regular expressions” FTW, most advanced editors support them. ETA: See FHZ's answer.

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:macros] as this should be used only for TeX macros.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are an art of its own. Unfortunately some editors have problems with them. TeXstudio for example has some difficult to handle multiple line searchs as said in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499994/multiple-line-regular-expression-in-texstudio). It took me some time to recognize and learn about this limitation.

Therefore, I will present three solutions.

### First solution

Use https://regexr.com/.

This site helps a lot to test regular expressions and is a little bit better than TeXstudio. Copy your text into the `Text` are, insert both search and replace syntax and copy the results.

The syntax you are looking for is: `\\solution\{((.|\n)+?)\}`, and the replace syntax is: `\begin{solution}$1\end{solution}`.

The base text and result is presented below

```
\solution{
  ABC
  BCD
  CDE
}

\solution{
  D
  E 
}

\solution{
  F
}
```

[image]

**Warning**: I don't know if this syntax will work for *anything* inside your macro. I wrote it to stop when finding `}`.

### Second solution

Search with `F3`, replace with `F4`.

First step is to configure some `Shortcuts` in TeXstudio. I suggest `F4` combinations for `Replace`; `Shift+F4` for `Replace Prev`; and `Ctrl+Shift+F4` for `Replace All`. So you can search with `F3` and replace with `F4` as fast as you can without replacing non desired text.

[image]

In this solution, you'll do two sets of searchs. First, `\solution{` to `\begin{solution}`. This replacement will probably be possible with `Ctrl+Shift+F4`.

[image]

The second set is looking for `}` and replacing for `\end{solution}`. This is clearly the main drawback of this solution. It is not so simple to identify a single `}` that is the exactly match for the previously `\solution{` without actually search through lines and keeping record of *opens* and *closes* along the way. Therefore the `F3` and `F4` trick makes you do this search automatically and replace manually.

[image]

[image]

*Edit: It may be easier if you search and replace first for `}` and then `\solution{`*.

### Third solution

Well, this may not be an elegante solution, but let's *cheat* a little bit with the tools we have.

Let's assume the only `}` in your file are the *closure* of your `\solution{`, in this case the *cheat* is to replace them first and then the `\solution{`. It probably is not a good solution for a file with many thing mixed, but it is a good example of how to avoid complex `regex` syntax by splitting the problem in small pieces.

As you asked for a TeXstudio macro, let's use it to. The syntax is

```
%SCRIPT
editor.replace(/\}/,"g","\\end{solution}")
editor.replace(/\\solution\{/,"g","\\begin{solution}")
```

where `%SCRIPT` is mandatory, and the `/.../` are used for `regex` expression, despite not being strictly necessary in our case. Also notice the double `\\` because we need one `\` for the `LaTeX` command and the first is to recognize the second.

[image]

And *voilá*, it works like a charm, a cheap and cheated charm, but a charm.

### Conclusion

Aim for the first solution, learn how to use de second to handle special cases, keep the third in your pocket for emergencies.

Answer (score 1):

In TeXStudio replace option with regex doesn't support new lines match for some reason.

So I came up with a trick where you grab all text in your document as a string and apply regex to it and new lines will be matched as well.

Here's a macro that solves your problem. Note that it also support any nested curly brackets as well.

```
%SCRIPT
regexParsed = editor.text().replace(/\\solution{([^}{]*({.*})*[^}{]*)}/gm, '\\begin{solution}$1\\end{solution}').replace(/\r/g, '');
editor.setText(regexParsed)
```

[image]

Comment: I’m grateful for your help!! It really work.