# Shortcut for replacing $$ $$ with align or equation?

Tags: equations, align

I usually use the $$ sign to do in-line equations. But often I realize I want to number it, or turn it into a sequence of aligned equations. I then manually copy and paste the equation out of the $$ $$, type \begin{ equation} and then paste the equation in. Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: This depends on the functionalities displayed by your editor.

Comment: If your editor supports regex search, then it could be the way to go

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `$$` in a LaTeX document to begin with. Please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for more information on this subject.

Comment: @Mico didn't know that! I don't understand the answer in that post, but I'll believe it.  So replacing $$ $$ in my question with \[ \] , is there a shortcut?

Comment: Not with LaTeX or most editors.  You could write a program in another language to replace the even and odd occurrences of $$ with `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: you are asking about editing a file but have not said what editor you are using. latex itself is not really involved here

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639398/140133) shows how to use regular expressions (regex) in a separated website and in TeXstudio.

Answer (score 4):

You have not said what editor you are using. Any reasonable editor should be able to make that edit.

Or you could use a commandline tool such as perl.

For example if `file.tex` is

```
$$ 1=1$$

qqqq
$$
2=2
$$


qqqq
$$
2=2
+1
-1
$$
```

then

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/\\begin{equation}$1\\end{equation}/sg' file.tex >file2.tex
```

will create a `file2.tex` that looks like

```
\begin{equation} 1=1\end{equation}

qqqq
\begin{equation}
2=2
\end{equation}


qqqq
\begin{equation}
2=2
+1
-1
\end{equation}
```

Note I suggest writing  new file rather than doing an in-place edit as it gives you a chance to check the output. (For example this one-liner is not checking mis-matched `$$` that may appear in comments or macros or `verbatim` etc)